# NullPointerException when inflating , inside the graphical designer

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-custom-view, layout-inflater, graphical-layout-editor

I'm creating a custom view that extends from FrameLayout.

in each of the CTORs , i'm using a LayoutInflater to inflate some views from XML , using something like this (in a function called "init()" ) :

```
final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, this, true); // <= here there is an NPE
```

the problem is, even though the app works fine with this code, the graphical designer constantly fails to render the custom view- it keeps writing something like this in the error log:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.example.customviewtest.CustomView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not resolve resource value: 0x7F030018.
    at android.content.res.BridgeResources.throwException(BridgeResources.java:693)
    at android.content.res.BridgeResources.getLayout(BridgeResources.java:271)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
    at com.example.customviewtest.CustomView.init(CustomView .java:38)
    at com.example.customviewtest.CustomView.<init>(CustomView .java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:422)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:179)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
```

it seems to occur only sometimes, and i don't understand on which cases. it's like the real code is not in sync with the graphical editor. sometimes it even claims i'm trying to cast a view to a totally different type of view.

### my question

why does it occur? is it an ADT bug?

i've tried multiple ways to use the inflater, including :

```
getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)
```

and i also tried to do the inflating on the onFinishInflate method, but nothing worked.

it seems that many have posted about this problem, but none found a solution and simply used isInEditMode for disabling the inflating in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your R Class file and find what points to **0x7F030018**

***Edit***

You must add

```
if (!isInEditMode())
{
   // Your major LayoutInflater codes goes here
}
```

in your custom view's constructor. Then it'll build.

Comment: it doesn't matter. no matter what is the layout file. even the most simplest one will cause this. anyway, it belongs to the layout file itself (R.layout.custom_view) .

Comment: anyway, i thought i've fixed it somehow (it stopped having errors for some reason, no idea what caused it) , but the bug has returned . it's like the graphical designer isn't in sync with the code.

Comment: But you are able to run the application. Right?

Comment: in both cases (when i had the bug and when i didn't) , it worked fine. weird , right? i'm quite sure it's an ADT problem.

Comment: Even I have the same issue. I can run the application. But, I get error in graphical designer :D

Comment: but if i remove this part, i won't get the nice preview of the custom view, and i will need to add similar code to make it look well... i think it's a bug. another bug is that if i use the class IcsLinearLayout from actionBarSherlock library (or something else, i am not sure) , and show it on the graphical editor, it will show only on the main preview, but the small previews will have an error, and if i set the API to 16 instead of 17 in the graphical editor, it looks just fine.

Comment: Did you export to android studio and check if this error is there in that IDE as well?

Comment: no, but that's an interesting idea. the weird part of this bug is that i have no idea when it occurs.

Comment: i've now tried to work with the new IDE. i am so lost when i try to use it. it's so different. i've tried to put a custom view that i know that is problematic , as it uses the IcsLinearLayout from actionBarSherlock library. i think i've failed importing the library. it's so weird compared to eclipse (and even VS). i will try again later with a simpler code.

Comment: Ok. I'll try importing mine into it and let you know.